I have a problem connecting laravel to my database even if i enabled pdo_mysql
This is the error when i try to run php artisan migrate:
     Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

  could not find driver (Connection: mysql, SQL: select exists (select 1 from information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'fitnessapp' and table_name = 'migrations' and table_type in ('BASE TABLE', 'SYSTEM VERSIONED')) as `exists`)

  at vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:825
    821▕                     $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    822▕                 );
    823▕             }
    824▕
  ➜ 825▕             throw new QueryException(
    826▕                 $this->getName(), $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    827▕             );
    828▕         }
    829▕     }

  1   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:66
      PDOException::("could not find driver")

  2   vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:66
      PDO::__construct()

I have the right drivers enabled like so:
extension=pdo_mysql
and I have configured the .env file correctly to match the data from the database that i created in phpmyadmin page.
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=fitnessapp
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

Do i need to install something else(i have tried recreating the laravel project but i get the same error) how to fix this error?

I just needed to put a path for the ext folder in the php.ini file
like that "C:\xampp\php\ext" by default it was "ext"

You need to ensure that you have the PHP Extension "PDO" installed. Laravel is not providing your PHP installation. I assume that you are using Windows here is how to install it: How do I install PDO drivers for PHP on Windows?
